# Where to define non-class method?

Tags: java

I am defining a function in Java that doesn't use class object. It is simply used to convert the string input from the user to an integer. No matter where I place the function I get and error. I was wondering where I should place it. Here it is

```
//Basically, when the user enters character C, the program stores
// it as integer 0 and so on.

public int suit2Num(String t){
   int n=0;
   char s= t.charAt(0);
   switch(s){
   case 'C' :{ n=0; break;}
   case 'D': {n=1;break;}
   case 'H':{ n=2;break;}
   case 'S': {n=3;break;}
   default: {System.out.println(" Invalid suit letter; type the correct one. ");
            break;}
   }
return n;   
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Just create one `Util` class(ex: `ConvertionUtil.java`) and put this method as a `static` method there.

```
public class ConvertionUtil{

public static int suit2Num(String t){
    ---
}

}
```

**Usage:**

```
int result = ConvertionUtil.suit2Num(someValidStirng);
```

Comment: Note: A "good" static method should not refer to anything other than the inputs passed. This way you will not impact the test-ability of your code.

Answer (score 8):

You define it inside a class (everything is a class in Java), but make it `static`:

```
public class MyClass {

    //Basically, when the user enters character C, the program stores
    // it as integer 0 and so on.
    public static int suit2Num(String t){
        int n=0;
        char s= t.charAt(0);
        switch(s) {
            case 'C' :{ n=0; break;}
            case 'D': {n=1;break;}
            case 'H':{ n=2;break;}
            case 'S': {n=3;break;}
            default: {
                System.out.println(" Invalid suit letter; type the correct one. ");
                break;
            }
        }
        return n;   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use exception like this"

```
public class MyClass {

//Basically, when the user enters character C, the program stores
// it as integer 0 and so on.
    public static int suit2Num(String t) throws InvalidInputException{
        int n=0;
        char s= t.charAt(0);
        switch(s) {
            case 'C' :{ n=0; break;}
            case 'D': {n=1;break;}
            case 'H':{ n=2;break;}
            case 'S': {n=3;break;}
            default: {
                throw new InvalidInputException();
            }
        }
        return n;   
    }
}
```

And you can use only static methods of classes where you need like this:

```
package com.example;

import static MyClass;

public class MMMain{

public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println(suit2Num("Cassandra"));
            System.out.println(suit2Num("Wrong line"));
        } catch(InvalidInputException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```